# I need to add telephone field on customer registration page in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I need to enable telephone field on Registration page in magento 2.Any guide how to do this.

Comment: Telephone is not a customer attribute, its address attribute so you cannot add it directly to customer form. If you add it forcefully then it will not be saved as its not a customer attribute. If you need to add then you can create one custom customer attribute for telephone.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, you need to insert the required field(telephone in your case) into the table. I will always encourage to accomplish this using a custom module, although it is time taking, it is a standard and cleanest way.

1. Create a standard module with minimal required files.
2. Create InstallData.php in the following path NameSpace\ModuleName\Setup

```
namespace NameSpace\ModuleName\Setup;

  use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
  use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
  use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
  use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;


  class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
  {

      /**
       * CustomerSetupFactory
       * @var CustomerSetupFactory
       */
      protected $customerSetupFactory;

      /**
       * $attributeSetFactory
       * @var AttributeSetFactory
       */
      private $attributeSetFactory;

      /**
       * initiate object
       * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
       * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
       */
      public function __construct(
          CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
          AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
      )
      {
          $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
          $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
      }

      /**
       * install data method
       * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
       * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
       */
      public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
      {

          /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
          $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

          $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
          $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

          /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
          $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
          $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
          /**
           * customer registration form default field mobile number
           */
          $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'telephone', [
              'type' => 'varchar',
              'label' => 'Telephone',
              'input' => 'text',
              'required' => true,
              'visible' => true,
              'user_defined' => true,
              'sort_order' => 1000,
              'position' => 1000,
              'system' => 0,
          ]);
          //add attribute to attribute set
          $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'telephone')
              ->addData([
                  'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                  'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                  'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create'],
              ]);

          $attribute->save();


      }
  }
```

3. Add the field to the frontend by copying module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml to app/design/frontend/namespace/theme/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml and add

   ```
           <div class="field required">
           <label for="telephone" class="label"><span><?= __('Telephone') ?></span></label>
           <div class="control">
           <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php echo __('Telephone') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-phoneStrict':true}">
           </div>
           </div>
   ```
4. Clear cache and check the code on register page.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

Run this setup script from Magento root:

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php'); 
umask(0);
Mage::app();


$installer = new Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$installer->startSetup();

$vCustomerEntityType = $installer->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$vCustAttributeSetId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($vCustomerEntityType);
$vCustAttributeGroupId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($vCustomerEntityType, $vCustAttributeSetId);

$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'cust_telephone', array(
        'label' => 'Customer Telephone',
        'input' => 'text',
        'type'  => 'varchar',
        'forms' => array('customer_account_edit','customer_account_create','adminhtml_customer','checkout_register'),
        'required' => 0,
        'user_defined' => 1,
));

$installer->addAttributeToGroup($vCustomerEntityType, $vCustAttributeSetId, $vCustAttributeGroupId, 'mobile', 0);

$oAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'cust_telephone');
$oAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_account_edit','customer_account_create','adminhtml_customer','checkout_register'));
$oAttribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

Attribute "cust_telephone" will be added. Use these codes in the register form:

```
<li class="fields"> <div class="field"> <label><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Customer Telephone') ?></label> <div class="input-box"> <input type="text" name="cust_telephone" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getCust_Telephone()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Customer Telephone') ?>" class="input-text" /> </div> </div> </li>
```

Now, you will find the telephone field in the customer registration page.
[image]

Comment: the solution would never work with magento2, which is clearly asked in the question.

Comment: can you add validation code in it ?